# Getting different words at the time of maxpooling

Tags: conv-neural-network, text-classification, word-embedding, max-pooling

I am doing text classification using CNN.

Let’s say features are a 6×3 matrix and the kernel dimension is 2×3, stride = 1, without padding we will get an output vector 1×5.

[image]

Now if we add padding to make the output vector 1*6, I get two types of output vectors depending upon the padding location. If I add padding at the beginning of Word2vec embedding matrix I get a  vector, like

[image]

If I add padding at end of the word2vec embedding matrix I get a vector like
[image]

The problem is with maxpooling.

The highest value 0.61 represents two different words for two different type of padding.

What should I do to make the maxpooling a unique word?